# Oracle not recognizing day and month functions in JPA Criteria API after migrating from WildFly 21 to 29

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I recently migrated my application (don't use spring boot) from WildFly 21 to WildFly 29. In the older version, I was using the following Hibernate dialect, which is no longer working:

I'm using JPA's Criteria API to build a dynamic query. I need to extract the day and month from a Date field to filter results. I'm using the CriteriaBuilder's function method to call Oracle database functions day and month on a date field. However, Oracle doesn't seem to recognize either of these functions.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = this.manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Servidor> cq = cb.createQuery(Servidor.class);
Root<Servidor> root = cq.from(Servidor.class);

jakarta.persistence.criteria.Path<Date> dataAnivPath = root.<Date>get("dataNascimento");
Expression<Integer> mesAnivPath = cb.function("month", Integer.class, dataAnivPath);
Expression<Integer> diaAnivPath = cb.function("day", Integer.class, dataAnivPath);
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: What hibernate dialect did you use before update? And what hibernate dialect do you use now?

Comment: I has used <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />. But, it look likes don't work anymore on wildfly 29